# accessing arraylist elemnts in javascript from jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am passing a arraylist from jsp to javascript.
How to access the elements of arraylist in javascript

jsp code:

```
<%out.print(arraylist)%>
```

javascript

```
var http = createRequestObject();
var reponse=http.responseText
```

Comment: Are you using JSTL? or do you want to handle this only with scriptlets.

Comment: in jsp i am using sciptlets to pass arraylist

Answer (score 0):

If you are using scriptlets then you need to iterate like java code.

Example Snippet:

```
<% 
    Iterator itr = arrayList.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
     System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
%>
```

Comment: you are telling how me to access arraylist values in jsp,what i require is to access arraylist elements in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the Arraylist in your scriptlet and assign the necessary value to the javascript variable as below..

Rough code

```
<% 
Iterator it = arrayList.iterator(); 
while(it.hasNext()){
%>
<script> var val = <%=itr.next()%>  </script>

<%}%>
```

Hope it helps!!

EDIT:

```
<script>
    var someArray = [
    <c:forEach items="${someArray}" var="it">
    {
        name = "<c:out value="${it.name}">",
        val = "<c:out value="${it.val}">"
    },
    </c:forEach>
    ];
</script>
```

The above will result in javascript like this,

```
var someArray = [
{
    name = "Peter",
    val = "First Name"
},
{
    name = "Naveen",
    val = "Last Name"
}];
```

Comment: As you see my arraylist is passed as out.print(arraylist) to javascript,so how to access this arraylist elements in javascript

Comment: For that you need to serialize them as javascript.. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JSTL to iterate.

Add the taglib

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

Code to iterate arraylist

```
<c:forEach items="${arraylist}" var="current">
   <c:out value="${current}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: isnt there any way in javascript to access this arraylist

Comment: You can iterate arraylist in javascript but before that you need to know the type of elements in that arraylist. Whether it will be string or object type???

Comment: arraylist contain elements of array type

Comment: Do u mean that your arraylist has list of array elements inside.
Like arraylist.add(array1); arraylist.add(array2);

Comment: Using JSON is easy to achieve this. You can use JSONArray and convert the arraylist to json. Then in javascript you can iterate the JSON

Answer (score 0):

Using JSON is easy to achieve this. You can use JSONArray and convert the arraylist to json in JSP or java. Then in javascript you can iterate the JSON like

```
for(var i=0;i<jsonArr.length;i++){
        var obj = jsonArr[i];
        for(var key in obj){
            var attrName = key;
            var attrValue = obj[key];
        }
    }
```